# Python - SSL Error when making API call with urllib.request

Tags: python, ssl, urllib, github-api

I'm trying to make a HTTPS API call in a Python script that will be included in an Azure DevOps pipeline step. I'm restricted to using `urllib.request`.

The current code I have is:

```
try:
    os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = '<redacted>'
    os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = '<redacted>'
    req = urllib.request.Request(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repository_name}/languages')
    req.add_header('Accept', 'application/vnd.github+json')
    req.add_header('Authorization', f'Bearer {github_token}')
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=f'{cert_path}')
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=ssl_context) as response:
        gt_response = json.load(response)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error. [{e}]')
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1091)>

I'm not an SSL expert and this has totally stumped me for what I would expect to be a simple operation. I've looked through the [urllib.request documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) but to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely the proxy you use is blocking the access

Comment: I am supplying the proxy details and I believe it should allow access.

Comment: *"and I believe it should allow access"* - what is the base for this believe? What kind of proxy is this. i.e. just to get outside or has it a security purpose?